# How to add substitute in Azure yaml?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

What is the equivalent of this in azure yaml?
Using the parameters

```
echo 'y' | sfdx plugins:install @dxatscale/sfpowerscripts@${SFPOWERSCRIPTS_VERSION:-"alpha"}
```

Is it this way?

```
parameters:
  - name: sfpowerscripts_version
    type: string

echo 'y' | sfdx plugins:install @dxatscale/sfpowerscripts@${{ parameters.sfpowerscripts_version:-"alpha" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this official doc for the guidance to use Parameters in Azure DevOps YAML: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script

Modified as below:

```
parameters:
  - name: sfpowerscripts_version
    type: string

echo 'y' | sfdx plugins:install @dxatscale/sfpowerscripts@${{ parameters.sfpowerscripts_version }}:-"alpha"
```